# How to remove a GitHub account that's attached to VS code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3Tv.png)

I'm not sure what to do I've tried uninstalling VS code but that didn't work. Please Help!

I'm not sure why i have to add 220 characters so just disregard this part of the body as I'm just typing in nonsense till i can post this request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS Code. You need to be logged in to GitHub before you can push to a repository hosted on GitHub. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line or use a personal access token https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Comment: (The 220 characters requirement is to encourage people to actually write out their question in words instead of posting a screenshot and asking "please help")